# Find methods without JavaDoc in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

In IntelliJ, is there a way to get a list of all methods without JavaDoc for a certain class?

A package?

A module?

A project?

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? If you only want to see them, open a class and press `Ctrl` + `F12`. To search for all methods (and variables etc) in your entire project, Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `N`.

Comment: That's giving me a list of methods, but not a list of methods that are missing JavaDocs... By "get", I mean a quick and easy way to identify them. A search would be cool, as would be the possibility to add an Inspection rule on an Error level for methods without JavaDocs. The important bit really is the "methods *without JavaDocs*"... :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to `Settings > Editor > Inspections > Javadoc issues > Declaration has Javadoc problems`.

On the right side you can configure the scope (package, class, method, ...) and the visibility (public, private, ...) to show warnings for missing JavaDocs.

Finally run `Analyze > Run inspection by name > Declaration has Javadoc problems` to search for all specified missing JavaDocs.

Comment: this does not show methods without any comments, shows only methods with incorrect comments

Comment: Needs to explicitly enable "Missing javadoc" inspection.